# Java Combination Generation

Tags: java, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I'm looking to see if java has some combinatorics features that I can utilize. I want to have a dynamic list, and in a clean way, have java generate all combinations.

Given a list of objects, such as strings below. Is there an easy way/clean way/preferably something already built into core java to generate all combinations of the items? e.g. If I had:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("a");
items.add("b");
List<List<String>> result = generateCombinationOf(items);
```

I desire for results to contain: `{{}, {"a"}, {"b"}, {"a", "b"}}`

**Side note:** I was able to generate lists like this in mathematica in the past. I have a side project where I want to utilize java and I'm hoping to avoid integrating with mathematica if at all possible, but will if I can't find some features like the above easily available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void generateCombinationOf(List<String> items,
        List<String> selected, int index, List<List<String>> result) {
    if (index >= items.size()) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(selected));
    } else {
        generateCombinationOf(items, selected, index + 1, result);
        selected.add(items.get(index));
        generateCombinationOf(items, selected, index + 1, result);
        selected.remove(selected.size() - 1);
    }
}

static List<List<String>> generateCombinationOf(List<String> items) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    generateCombinationOf(items, selected, 0, result);
    return result;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(generateCombinationOf(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
```

result

```
[[], [b], [a], [a, b]]
```

non-recursive version

```
static List<List<String>> generateCombinationOf(List<String> list) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, max = 1 << list.size(); i < max; ++i) {
        List<String> comb = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0, k = i; k > 0; ++j, k >>= 1)
            if ((k & 1) == 1)
                comb.add(list.get(j));
        result.add(comb);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Was looking for something built in, but will accept in a few days if no one else provides an example of something built in.

Comment: Java doesn't usually have built in functions for these kinds of things.

If the reason you want to have a function like this however is because you want to be able to call this directly on the list like `list.getCombinations();` you could make your own `MyList` class that extends ArrayList and implements this method. You can then just base that method upon the code in this solution.

Comment: @DanvanderKallen, I haven't seen anything like this in core java either, but I'm hoping there is a 3rd party jar (preferably by someone like apache, or other with a good open source reputation). Java has such a strong following that I find it hard to believe there isn't anything out there for this.

Comment: [github - combinatoricslib](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib)  seems to work? See Subsets section.
[Symja](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/Home) has also a lot of combinatoric functions but may be to much oversize. Try **Subsets({a,b})**